# Como criar uma índice composto no SQLite via Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio, uwp

Estou tentando criar um índice composto único, mas não sei como fazer isso no `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite`, eu estou acostumado a trabalhar apenas com o `Doctrine` e `Hibernate` e estou totalmente perdido.

Essa é minha classe modelo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test.Entity
{
    public class Project
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        private int id;
        [Required]
        private bool shared;
        [Required, MaxLength(64)]
        private String name;

        private Project parent;

        [ForeignKey("id")]
        private ICollection<Project> searchable;

        public bool Shared
        {
            get { return shared; }
            set { shared = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public Project Parent
        {
            get { return parent; }
            set { parent = value; }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public ICollection<Project> Searchable
        {
            get { return searchable; }
            set { searchable = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Esse é meu método na minha classe de contexto

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
   modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasIndex(r => new { r.Name, r.Parent}).IsUnique();
}
```

Comment: Um dica: [link de formatação de perguntas e resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... vai te auxiliar a criar perguntas com layout e configurações correta.

Comment: Um pergunta, você mandou um código de uma coisa e na configuração está fazendo um index de outra? não seria melhor postar a duvida com os itens de classe que faz a referencia da sua duvida? Ta meio desconectado um código do outro.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic obrigado, desculpa pelo erro, postei na hora do almoço e copiei o trecho errado que eu queria mostrar. Já editei e corrigi.

Comment: Não precisa pedir desculpas @SlienoBrito normal acontece, foi mais um alerta!

Comment: É um índice único `pk`? Um índice simples? Ou um índice composto?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow É um índice composto, eu cometi um erro na hora de postar a pergunta e ficou confusa.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizo um procedimento pouco diferente do seu porém o resultado deveria ser o mesmo:

```
 entityBuilder.HasIndex(c => new { c.AutorNome, c.Nome})
                .HasName("idx_Curso_Autor_Nome")
                .IsUnique();
```

Resultado no gerenciador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejo duas possibilidades para não conseguir gerar seu índice:

1. Não está executando o migration `Add-Migration IndiceComposto`
2. Você está usando `data annotation` junto com `fluent api`, melhor seria fazer tudo com `fluent api`. Note que na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys) informa que não é possível `composite keys` com `data annotations`. Sei que não está gerando o indice composto dessa forma mas é bom padronizar.

Respondendo mais especificamente a questão:

Penso não haver possibilidade de informar uma classe como indice.

Como o `EF` vai saber o que exatamente qual campo está querendo indexar?

> The property 'xxx' cannot be added to the entity type 'xxx'

Comment: Mas no exemplo da pergunta, seria para criar uma chave com o objeto Parent que é do tipo Project não com outra string.

Comment: Entendi, mas penso que como o banco não entende o que é `objeto Parent` ou talvez gere uma chave relacionada ao índice desta tabela, no caso a `ForeignKey`. Vou fazer outro teste mais tarde.

Comment: Consegui fazer, tem que criar um objeto do tipo no caso, pq o meu é índice é int e depois colocar a anotação no objeto e na hora de criar o índice composto você coloca a annotation no seu objeto do tipo int para aportar para o mapeamento. Não sei se vai funcionar, pq deu outro problema, mas na outra pergunta que fiz tem um exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175875/problemas-de-mapeamento-no-microsoft-entityframeworkcore não sei se deu para entender a explicação, tinha que criar um int ParentId e colocar annotation nele [ForeignKey("Parent")],

Comment: Retifica a resposta para funcionar com exemplo que eu aceito. E obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Na documentação citada na resposta diz que não é possível criar índices compostos pelo `data annotations`, talvez o erro esteja relacionado a isso.

Comment: Não da mesmo pelo que eu vi, devia ter sido:  {c.Name, c.ParentId} e criar ParentId e o ParentId ter sido associado ao Parent

Comment: Bem, editei a pergunta somente para esclarecer. Da maneira que estava fazendo penso não ser possível devido informar uma classe para ser indexada. Caso tenha sucesso da forma que postou informe.