# Problemas de mapeamento no Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio, uwp

Estou tentando criar em uma classe dois Mapeamentos ManyToOne usando annotation do `Entity Framework`, porém não estou conseguindo, se eu tirar qualquer um dos dois mapeamentos e deixar o outro, funciona porém se eu deixar os dois da erro. O projeto está sendo feito em C# no visual studio, o tipo do projeto é UWP (Universal Windows Platform). Estou usando o MicrosoftEntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite versão 1.1.0 O Banco de dados que estou modelando é SQLite.

Essa é a mensagem de erro que recebo:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Sentence.FirstTerm' of type 'Term'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyMappingValidationConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.Validate()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Validate()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetModel>b__0(Object k)
   em System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddEntityFramework>b__0_6(IServiceProvider p)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactoryService(FactoryService factoryService, ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ConfigureContextServices>b__9(IServiceProvider _)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactoryService(FactoryService factoryService, ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   em Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Sentence.FirstTerm' of type 'Term'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.
```

Essa é minha classe Term:

```
namespace Test.Entity
{
    public class Term
    {
        public Term() {
            FirstTerms = new List();
            LastTerms = new List();
        }
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        protected int id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        [InverseProperty("FirstTerm")]
        public virtual ICollection FirstTerms { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("LastTerm")]
        public virtual ICollection LastTerms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Essa é minha classe Sentence:

```
namespace Test.Entity
{
    public class Sentence : Term
    {
        [ForeignKey("Rule")]
        public int RuleId { get; set; }
        public Rule Rule { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Operation")]
        public int OperationId { get; set; }
        public Operation Operation { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FirstTerm")]
        public int FirstTermId { get; set; }
        public virtual  Term FirstTerm { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("LastTerm")]
        public int LastTermId { get; set; }
        public virtual Term LastTerm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Essa é minha classe de contexto (exite mais conteúdo nela, porém nenhum deles é referente a classe Term ou Sentence):

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Entity().HasIndex(r => r.FirstTermId);
            modelBuilder.Entity().HasIndex(r => r.LastTermId);

        }
```

O erro aparece quando eu executo o comando:

> Add-Migration Vanilla

Se na classe `Sentence` eu remover o `LastTerm` e deixar o `FirstTerm` ou ainda remover `FirstTerm` e deixar `LastTerm` o `Migration` executa sem erro.

Referencias do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: As duas `ForeignKey` estão relacionadas com `Term` me parece incorreto.

Comment: Essa sentença é uma sentença matemática, no exemplo acima seria o primeiro termo e o ultimo termo e a operação matemática, por isso preciso dos dois, esse termo pode ser uma constante, por exemplo que é outra classe que estende termo, por isso preciso dos dois, mas pode ser que a notação esteja errada, aceito sugestão.

Comment: Pegou este exemplo de algum local? Tem o link?

Comment: Não, pode ser que esteja errada a notação!

Comment: Pelo que ele tentou fazer, está parecendo que ele quer fazer uma estrutura em Árvore no banco, ou estou errado? Mesmo assim, o que eu notei é que o Attribute  [ForeignKey("Operation")] está na propriedade errada também.